# Why can't I change the text background in Notepad++

Tags: styles, themes, notepad++

No matter what theme XML I use from the NPP Style Configurator, I can't change the background of existing text. Any help would be much appreciated!

I can't post images yet, but here is a link showing the issue:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hO0-L9KCy9oRinRmhlujMLKvfNC7HyvyUWUjx2nYpto/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: First, make sure you have the most up to date version; old versions have some bugs. then, take a look at this: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/notepad-plus-plus-change-font-color/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you are using latest version. [Click Here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
Current Version: 6.7.4
Then still if problem exists then go to Settings > Style Configurations.
Here you can change all settings like what is font color and it's background and in which language.

Ex. For HTML you can define color and background color of TAG , comment , Number , Attribute , Value etc.....so on....

Comment: @ProudPagan , Thank you......I would like to answer more question....Keep Asking...